# Suggestions joomla/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla

### I have two options to learn a new domain for CMS

1. Joomla
2. Wordpress

Kindly suggest me which one is much better and easy to learn so i can make my decision accordingly???

Comment: If you want to get useful answers, you need to provide more details in terms of desired site structure and content. Also see this more general answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is easier to learn how to customize.

However, Joomla is more powerful if you would like to add more functionality, such as a web shop.

Comment: MY SIR TOLD ME THE MOST RECENT VERSION OF JOOMLA IS VERY VERY EASY TO LEARN ... what do you say about that version i never checked currently i am just getting some info from others to choose the best one for me,,

Comment: I haven't worked the latest version of Joomla.

As usual, it depends on what you want to accomplish. If you want a simple, text content-based website, choose Wordpress. If you want to move towards a more multi-functional website (including e.g. a webshop) maybe you'd prefer Joomla. And if you want even more power, and a more professional tool, choose Drupal.

Comment: Faizan, yes, Wordpress is still much easier to learn than the latest version of Joomla. Each CMS has it's own strengths and weaknesses. While you can build any website with either platform Wordpress is great for brochure websites, blogs, company websites, etc, whereas Joomla is great for larger sites, intranet sites, shops, organisation websites with lots of categories and content, etc.